# Hide the url that i get from the Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting

I have an action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Play!", "Game", "Manage", match, null)
```

That generate the following URL

```
https://localhost:44398/Manage/Game?Columns=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BConnect4.Models.Column%5D&Name=Pippo&Data=30-05-2022&NextTurnPlayer=Player1&State=InCorso&UsernamePlayer1=Luca&UsernamePlayer2=Leonardo&CanWin=0
```

There is a way to get both the match but make it appear alone `https://localhost:44398/Manage/Game` or something like that?

Just for the sake of completeness this is the controller,

```
public ActionResult Game(Match match)
{  
    ViewBag.table = match.DrawTable(match);
    string user = User.Identity.GetUserName();

    if (match == null || (user != match.UsernamePlayer1 && user != match.UsernamePlayer2))
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i research around this, and im afraid it's not achievable.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1036066/How-to-hide-Url-parameter-ASP-Net-MVC

u can do one workaround using javascript which would explicitely HIDE from the display but you can't achieve singleton.